# How do I send categorized and grouped logs into Stackdriver using the Java Client Library?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'd like to aggregate multiple `log.info` `log.warning` and `log.error` calls, and possibly stack traces, into a single Stackdriver log line generated by the server interacting with my application code. The goal is to summarize a request handled by my Scala server, and then group as many logging statements as occurred during its execution, with any errors.

This is default behavior on GAE logging, but because I'm new to reading [Java API's](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/logging/Logging.html#write-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.cloud.logging.Logging.WriteOption...-), I'm having trouble figuring out how to:

1/ create a custom `MonitoredResource` (?) representing, e.g., "API server", then specifying category within it (e.g. "production"). Specifically, do I have to create these via the REST API, even though I'm only doing it once for my deployment? Can I use something like [Troposphere](https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) to define these in code and commit them in a repo?

2/ how the nouns `MonitoredResource`, `MonitoredResourceDescriptor`, `LogEntry`, `LogEntryOperation` and `logName` fit together, and where the categories "API Server" and "production" get defined, as well as logging statement groups like `GET /foobar -> 200 response + 1834 bytes` can be added (are those logNames?).

No need to write code for me, of course, but pointers and a  high level overview to save me trial and error would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group together multiple log entries for the same operation by using the LogEntryOperation field in the LogEntry (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry#LogEntryOperation).

In the Logs Viewer, you can group the log entries by filtering on the `operation.id` field using the advanced filters.

In the Java client library, you can set the Operation Id using https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/logging/LogEntry.Builder.html#setOperation-com.google.cloud.logging.Operation-

1) The Monitored Resources you can use is a curated set defined by Google. You cannot define your own type. The supported resources are listed in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/v2/resource-list.

2) Basic concepts are described in https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/basic-concepts.

Comment: Why can't I define my own `MonitoredResourceDescriptor`s? How am I supposed to log something like "successful login" at the application layer which might be spread between different services? Is it good practice to use to use Global for this?

Answer (score 1):

1) The [MonitoredResource](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/MonitoredResource.html) monitors what you configure in [MonitoredResourceDescriptor](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/MonitoredResourceDescriptor.html)

I assume you can create it anyway you want (REST API or with the client libraries).

2) I am unsure where you want to describe "API Server" or "Production", the MonitoredResourceDescriptor is how to setup what to monitor. The [LogEntry](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/logging/LogEntry.html) is the actual logs and the [LogName](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.33.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/logging/Logging.WriteOption.html#logName-java.lang.String-) is just a label you give this particular log. What you described should be something that a logEntry returns (the 200 code + other stuff).

I might be a bit confused at what you are asking. The best thing to do is to create a sample MonitoredResource and see how it works.